# Different name of application on iPhone then on iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone

the name of my application is a bit large due to which all of it is not visible when i install it on my iPhone so i was thinking of changing the ***bundle name*** to a smaller text...but i want the original app name to appear in on ***Apple Store*** as it is...can i use a different name for apple store then ***bundle name*** on **Xcode** file while uploading my application on ***iTunes Connect***??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the name of the application on the AppStore in the "Manage Your Applications" section of iTunes Connect, clicking on "Manage Localizations". This way you can translate the name of the app in different languages.

If you need to change the name of the Application as it appears on the iPhone's home screen, you need to do it in the Target configuration, not the project configuration. Expand the Targets group in Xcode, then single-click the item under that. It should share the name of your project, which is also the default name of the application that gets generated.

Press command-I to bring up the Info window, then navigate to the Build tag. Set the Configuration drop-down to read All Configurations, then look for a setting called Product Name under the Packaging heading. Change that value to the name you want for your compiled applications.

*NOTE: In iTunes Connect you can't change the app name if its either already been approved or is currently in review. To change the name, you must submit a new version of your app.*

Comment: If you change the name of a new version of the app, will current users of the app receive an update of this new version? I thought they will, but I have try it, and they don´t receive anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you name your binary while building is what it will show up as on the iPhone. Look for "Product Name" in the Target's build settings.